# Using proc sql commands in proc fcmp?

Tags: sql, sas, user-defined-functions

I'm new to SAS and trying to create a user defined function that involves proc sql, the simplified version of the function is below;

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.test;
function calculate(table1, var1, motherTable);
proc sql noprint;
     create table table1 as
     select var1 
     from motherTable;
quit;
return();
endsub;
```

However, when I run the program I get the following:

```
ERROR: Subroutine 'calculate' was not terminated with ENDSUB.
ERROR: File WORK.MOTHERTABLE.DATA does not exist.
```

I am terminating the function with endsub(), and I know that motherTable doesn't exist because it's an argument to the function that hasn't been defined yet. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thank you so much!

Comment: Since all you are doing is running SAS code I would just write that "function" as a macro instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, what you're doing is probably better done in a macro.  That's how you do things like this most of the time in SAS.

```
%macro calc_func(in_table=, out_table=, var=);

  proc sql noprint;
    create table &out_table. as
      select &var. 
      from &in_table.
    ;
  quit;
%mend calc_func;
```

Second of all, you *could* do this in a user defined function (or a user defined call routine, more likely, as there's nothing being returned here); but you'd have to do it *through* a macro, if my understanding is right.

Check [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/033-2013.pdf) for more information, or see the below example.

```
%macro calc_func();
  %let table1=%sysfunc(dequote(&table1.));
  %let var1=%sysfunc(dequote(&var1.));
  %let motherTable=%sysfunc(dequote(&motherTable.));

  %put _all_;

  proc sql;
    create table &table1. as (
      select &var1. 
      from sashelp.&motherTable.)
    ;
  quit;
%mend calc_func;

proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.test;
  function calculate(table1 $, var1 $, motherTable $);
    rc = run_macro('calc_func', motherTable, table1, var1 ); 
    return(rc);
  endsub;
quit;

options cmplib=work.funcs;
data _null_;
  x = calculate('newclass', 'age', 'class');
  put x=;
run;
```

Basically, `RUN_MACRO` takes the macro name as an argument, and then allows FCMP to create macro variables with the names of the FCMP variables (or passed parameters).  However, you have to remove their quotes, which is ... irritating.  Good reason not to do this, unless it's truly necessary, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The PROC SQL statement is ending the PROC FCMP compilation.  You should just write that as a macro.

```
%macro calculate(table1, var1, motherTable);
proc sql noprint;
  create table &table1 as
    select &var1 
    from &motherTable
  ;
quit;
%mend calculate;
```